# Jquery 1.6.1 .val() issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve a value from a hidden field.  This code worked fine with jquery 1.4.2 but since we upgraded to 1.6.1 or 1.6.4 it is just returning an empty string.

Here is the code in the jsp that is being used to retrieve the data:

```
var selected = "Doing My Job"   
var selectedField= "input:hidden[name="+selected+"_node_id]";
var selectedId= $(selectedField).val();
```

This is the html of the element itself

```
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="Doing My Job_node_id">
```

So I want selectedId to be 2 but instead I am getting ""

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the value of `selected` is bringing back the correct value?

Try putting the output into an alert just to make sure.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/pjdJH/ Just to be sure, you should put the attribute into quotes (they are mandatory).

Comment: I have alerted the value of selected and I am getting the correct value, again this worked in 1.4.2 but tried with 1.6.1 and 1.6.4 and it doesn't.   @Felix Kling, cant understand how it is working for you, I tried your link and it works for me in there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the name should be quoted:

```
var selectedField= 'input:hidden[name="'+selected+'_node_id"]';
```

**Edit:** Whatever, this doesn't seem to affect the final result. You should use your browser's development tools to inspect the contents of both the `selectedField` selector and the `$(selectedField)` object, e.g.:

```
console.log(selectedField, $(selectedField));
```

Comment: You are right, but the code seems to work without them as well: http://jsfiddle.net/pjdJH/

Comment: changing to put in the quotes worked staright away, dont understand why it worked in Felix Klings link though

Comment: It seems to be hit and miss as far as when it works and doesn't work with and without the quotes around the attribute value. It has always had the quotes around the attribute value in the API, I would just suggest always having the quotes around the attribute value to prevent having issues in the future.